# model.predict in keras giving same output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset of 10 million, each record having 4 parameters.
If I model using the following when I carry out `model.predict`, I get the same result.

```
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12,input_dim=4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(numpy.array(X1), numpy.array(Y1), epochs=50, batch_size=1000000, verbose=2)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on what you mean by 'I get the same result.'?

Comment: Even though my input is varying the prediction I get out of the model is the same.

Comment: I am using the json to save the model and then open it for prediction on a different system. Is it possible that this is causing a problem?